# Problema com o Loop e cálculo de Hora

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, datetime

Quero fazer um Programa, aonde ele Leia uma atividade, e o tempo gasto nela.

Exemplo: `Lavando o Portão, 10:30 as 12:00, tempo gasto 01:30`

Estou atualmente com 3 problemas:

- Do jeito que meu codigo esta atualmente não consigo colocar ele pra
  funcionar, devido ao calculo das horas.
- Eu coloquei que seria feitas 5 atividades, caso eu queria deixar sem um limite pré estabelecido.
- Também gostaria de colocar uma palavra chave pra ele me dizer o print, como por exemplo se eu digitar "fim", ele dá o print com todas as informações coletadas.

```
from datetime import datetime
atividade = [] #Lista de Serviços
hora_inicial = [] #Lista Hora Inicial
hora_final = [] #Lista Hora Final
contagem = 0
while contagem != 5:
    try:
        atividade_p = input(f'Digite o Nome do {contagem + 1}º Atividade: ')
        contagem += 1
        hora_inicia_p = input('Digite a hora Inicial: ')
        hora_final_p = input('Digite a hora Final: ')
        atividade.append(atividade_p)
        hora_inicial.append(hora_inicia_p)
        hora_final.append(hora_final_p)
        d = '$H:$M'
    except ValueError:
        print('Digite um valor valido. Exemplo 10:30')

atividade_1 = atividade [0]
hora_inicia_1 = hora_inicial [0]
hora_final_1 = hora_final [0]
valor_1 = (datetime.strftime(hora_final_1, d) - datetime.strftime(hora_inicia_1, d)

atividade_2 = atividade [1]
hora_inicia_2 = hora_inicial [1]
hora_final_2 = hora_final [1]
valor_2 = (datetime.strftime(hora_final_2, d) - datetime.strftime(hora_inicia_2, d)

atividade_3 = atividade [2]
hora_inicia_3 = hora_inicial [2]
hora_final_3 = hora_final [2]
valor_3 = (datetime.strftime(hora_final_3, d)- datetime.strftime(hora_inicia_3, d)

atividade_4 = atividade [3]
hora_inicia_4 = hora_inicial [3]
hora_final_4 = hora_final [3]
valor_4 = (datetime.strftime(hora_final_4, d) - datetime.strftime(hora_inicia_4, d)

atividade_5 = atividade [4]
hora_inicia_5 = hora_inicial [4]
hora_final_5 = hora_final [4]
valor_5 = (datetime.strftime(hora_final_5, d) - datetime.strftime(hora_inicia_5, d)

print(f'{atividade_1},{hora_inicia_1} ás {hora_final_1}, Tempo gasto {valor_1}')
print(f'{atividade_2},{hora_inicia_2} ás {hora_final_2}, Tempo gasto {valor_2}')
print(f'{atividade_3},{hora_inicia_3} ás {hora_final_3}, Tempo gasto {valor_3}')
print(f'{atividade_4},{hora_inicia_4} ás {hora_final_4}, Tempo gasto {valor_4}')
print(f'{atividade_5},{hora_inicia_5} ás {hora_final_5}, Tempo gasto {valor_5}')
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está usando [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), que converte uma data/hora em uma string. Mas você quer fazer o contrário: dada uma string contendo um horário, convertê-la para um [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). Então neste caso você deve usar [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) (note o "p" em vez do "f" no nome do método).

Além disso, o formato usado deve ser `%H:%M`, e não `$H:$M`, conforme consta na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
t = datetime.strptime('12:00', '%H:%M') - datetime.strptime('10:30', '%H:%M')
print(t) # 1:30:00
```

Além disso, dá para melhorar o código usando um único loop para imprimir todas as atividades. Outro detalhe é que na leitura das datas você não está validando-as (criei uma função para isso abaixo). E já que esta função valida as datas, eu posso retorná-las e guardá-las diretamente nas respectivas listas.

O detalhe é que, para imprimir os objetos `datetime`, eu tenho que usar `strftime` para imprimir somente a data e hora (pois por padrão o `datetime` é impresso com todos os campos). Por fim, a diferença entre as datas gera um objeto [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), que ao ser impresso usa o formato "horas:minutos:segundos". Para imprimir somente as horas e minutos, você pode remover os 3 últimos caracteres (pois, como você está usando somente horas e minutos para calcular a diferença, os segundos sempre serão zero):

```
atividade = []  # Lista de Serviços
hora_inicial = []  # Lista Hora Inicial
hora_final = []  # Lista Hora Final
contagem = 0
formato = '%H:%M'

def obter_horario(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(input(msg), formato)
        except ValueError:
            print('Digite um valor valido. Exemplo 10:30')

i = 1
while True:
    atividade_p = input(f'Digite o Nome da {i}º Atividade: ')
    atividade.append(atividade_p)
    hora_inicial.append(obter_horario('Digite a hora Inicial: '))
    hora_final.append(obter_horario('Digite a hora final: '))
    i += 1
    # se digitar "fim", sai do while, senão continua lendo as atividades
    if (input('Digite "fim" para calcular a duração das atividades (ou enter para adicionar outra atividade): ') == 'fim'):
        break


for ativ, inicio, fim in zip(atividade, hora_inicial, hora_final):
    duracao = fim - inicio
    print(f'{ativ},{inicio.strftime(formato)} às {fim.strftime(formato)}, Tempo gasto {str(duracao)[:-3]}')
```

Comment: Ficou até melhor, porém, agora está aparecendo a data :
Lava o portão,1900-01-01 10:30:00 às 1900-01-01 12:00:00, Tempo gasto 1:30:00

Comment: Vocé teria algum lugar aonde eu posso está aprendendo mais? tenho internet reduzida, e os pdf que eu achei, so tem o básico.

Comment: @Ruamms Arrumei o código. Quanto ao material de estudo, eu geralmente uso a documentação oficial da internet: https://docs.python.org/3/ - lá tem um link pra vc baixar os pdfs: https://docs.python.org/3/download.html